# Django 1.10 KeyError at /admin/

Tags: python, django

I have a Django app that was written in Django 1.7, that I am porting to a Docker app.  I'm using Django 1.10 in the container.

When I browse to the /admin/ URI, I get the following exception:

```
KeyError at /admin/

u'user'

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:        http://10.3.101.206:9000/admin/
Django Version:     1.10
Exception Type:     KeyError
Exception Value:    

u'user'

Exception Location:     /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/context.py in __getitem__, line 75
Python Executable:  /usr/local/bin/python
Python Version:     2.7.12
Python Path:    

['/var/www/django/labmgr',
 '/usr/local/lib/python27.zip',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages']

Server time:    Tue, 20 Dec 2016 21:43:21 -0800

Error during template rendering

In template /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/index.html, error at line 58
user

48  {% endif %}
49  </div>
50  {% endblock %}
51  
52  {% block sidebar %}
53  <div id="content-related">
54      <div class="module" id="recent-actions-module">
55          <h2>{% trans 'Recent actions' %}</h2>
56          <h3>{% trans 'My actions' %}</h3>
57              {% load log %}
58              {% get_admin_log 10 as admin_log for_user user %}
59              {% if not admin_log %}
60              <p>{% trans 'None available' %}</p>
61              {% else %}
62              <ul class="actionlist">
63              {% for entry in admin_log %}
64              <li class="{% if entry.is_addition %}addlink{% endif %}{% if entry.is_change %}changelink{% endif %}{% if entry.is_deletion %}deletelink{% endif %}">
65                  {% if entry.is_deletion or not entry.get_admin_url %}
66                      {{ entry.object_repr }}
67                  {% else %}
68                      <a href="{{ entry.get_admin_url }}">{{ entry.object_repr }}</a>
```

The error appears to be in the Django code, and not my code, so I'm not sure what the problem is or how to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `KeyError` hints that the `user` context variable could not be found. That variable is only available through `django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth` which is normally included by default.

You can include it in your context processors as described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/upgrading/):

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            # insert your TEMPLATE_DIRS here
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                # ...list other context processors you will need...
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: Thanks.  I upgraded the Django code, but migrated my old code and settings so I did not get the default values in my settings.